# Intercepting touch event and re-directing it depending on motion event state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, touch-event

I've created a custom view in Android that inherits from RelativeLayout. Inside this view is an OverScroller which is used to handle scrolling of the view when a touch event occurs:

```
class MyCustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    private val scroller = OverScroller(context, FastOutLinearInInterpolator())
    private var currentY = 0
    private val gestureDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(context, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            // Stop the current scroll animation
            scroller.forceFinished(true)
            // Invalidate the view
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this@MyCustomView)
            return true
        }

        override fun onScroll(event1: MotionEvent?, event2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
            scroller.forceFinished(true)
            currentY -= distanceY.toInt()
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this@MyCustomView)
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
            // Stop any scrolling
            scroller.forceFinished(true)
            scroller.fling(0, currentY, 0, velocityY.toInt(), 0, 0,
                    -5000 + height, 0)
            // Invalidate the view
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this@MyCustomView)
            return true
        }
    })

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event == null) return false
        // Return the value from the gesture detector
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        // Draw stuff to canvas, using currentY as origin
    }

    override fun computeScroll() {
        // Call to super class method
        super.computeScroll()
        if (scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            currentY = scroller.currY
        }
        // Invalidate the view
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this@MyCustomView)
    }
}
```

This works fine. Next, I added a `RelativeLayout` view group to hold a load of inflated cells. These cells are clickable. Now, when I try to initiate a scroll with the first touch on one of these inflated cells, the cell swallows the click event (the parent view with the scroller never get's it's `onTouchEvent` called and therefore doesn't scroll).

Important to note: The `RelativeLayout` view group which holds the cells is a `child` view of `MyCustomView`.

I've tried overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` in `MyCustomView` in order to intercept the touch event before it is dispatched to either view like so:

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event == null) return false
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (event.historySize > 0) {
            val startY = event.getHistoricalY(0)
            val endY = event.getHistoricalY(event.historySize - 1)
            val distance = Math.abs(endY - startY).toInt()
            if (distance == 0) {
                // Consider this a click (so don't swallow it
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    // Ok this isn't a click, so call this views onTouchEvent
    return this.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

I then determine if the touch event's action code is `ACTION_UP`, if it is I calculate the total distance between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` and, if it's in a small enough range, I treat it as a click and call `super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)` (which will click an inflated cell if the event was on a cell, else it will end up calling my `onTouchEvent` which will handle scrolling. If the event's action code was not `ACTION_UP` OR the distance moved was not small enough, it will return `this.onTouchEvent(event)`.

The problem I'm having is that my solution isn't working, scrolling still cannot be initiated when starting the scroll on top of an inflated cell.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: No, I have implemented `computeScroll()`. Does `computeScroll()` get called regardless of if `onTouchEvent()` is called? I will edit the question to show my `computeScroll()` implementation now.

Comment: Thankyou pskink - reviewing now

Comment: Nah I always just look at source.

Comment: do you need `getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` somewhere?